# javascript code freezes the browser and the code only works in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, google-chrome

I have a form for which all text boxes should be filled before submission. my form looks like this

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="url" onsubmit="return checkEmpty(this)" >
<div class="field">
<label>field1</label><input type="text" name="f1" />
</div>
<div class="field">
<label>field2</label><input type="text" name="f2" />
</div>
..
....
......
input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

what i do here is that when a form is submitted i check if any text box is empty and if there is any i create a `dom` element `h3` and append it to the `div` of that corresponding field and if the text box is not empty i check if there is any text box attached to that corresponding field and if i find one i remove it. here is my javascript code

```
function checkEmpty(form) {
   var textboxes=form.elements;
   for(var i=0;i<textboxes.length;i++)
   {
      if((textboxes[i].type=="text" || textboxes[i].type=="password") && textboxes[i].textLength==0)   //text box is empty                     
      {
         var msg=document.createElement('h3');
         msg.innerHTML="u cant leave this field blank";
         textboxes[i].parentNode.appendChild(msg);
         return false;
      }
      else                      //text box is not empty
      {
         var rem_msg=textboxes[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName('h3');
         for(var j=0;j<rem_msg.length;j++)
            textboxes[i].parentNode.removeChild(rem_msg[j]);
      }
   }
}
```

**Now the browser freezes when i submit the form.**
**Also my code doesnt work in ggogle chrome but only firefox**
Until i was not removing elements the code was working fine but removing element is neccessary because say a user doesnt enter any value in text box 1 on first attempt so an `h3` element would be added but now he enters some text in first text box but leaves second text box empty so the `h3` element of first text box should dissappear.

---

> because of the answer below the code
>   is no more freezing the browser but
>   still i am only able to add `h3`
>   elements to the dom but cannot remove
>   them.also the code works in firefox
>   but not in google chrome.

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery? This is way more code than you need for something like this.

Comment: Justin Morgan: i know that dis is a wierd approach but i wonder why the browser is crashing? the only reason i can understand is that the js execution cant stop like an infinite loop but i dont see any thing like that in the code

Comment: I think @Martin has the right answer, but I also notice there's no `return` statement in your `else` block. Whether that would throw an error or cause a freeze probably depends on the browser, but it could be a problem. You're calling `return checkEmpty(this)` when `checkEmpty(this)` might not have a return value.

Comment: @Justin Morgan: may be you are rigtht. The code is not working in google chrome.its just working in firefox. but if put a `return` in `else` block then even if a single text box is non-empty the form wud be submitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is you are using the variable `i` in two distinct loops. When the inner loop finishes it will always end up setting `i` to `rem_msg.length`, which will keep the outer loop from ever reaching its exit condition so you end up with an infinite loop.

To fix your problem you simply need to rename the second `i` to e.g. `j` and you're good to go.

Comment: thanks that worked but anothe problem. the `h3` element is not being removed once i enter some text in the text box and submit and moreover the code is not working in google chrome,not even the `appendElement`. its just working in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be the malformed `for`:

```
for(var i=0;i<rem_msg.length;;i++)
```

You have an extra `;` so I think the `i++` isn't getting run.

Comment: no its not because of that.i corrected it but still the same problem